# Who should our beta moderators be?

Tags: discussion, 7-questions, moderators

Given our successful private beta, soon after we go public it will be time for us to get our first crop of moderators, as explained in the [“Moderator Pro Tempore” blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/):

> About a week into the public beta, we will seek out members who are deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:
>
> - Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
> - Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
> - Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
> - Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [*A Theory of Moderation*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).
>
> Bonus points for:
>
> - Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
> - Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
> - Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.
>
> Candidates will be contacted and three of them will be selected to act as provisional Moderators until the community holds formal elections after the Beta period. Besides the normal abilities of a Moderator, they will:
>
> - Have access to a special chat room where we will collectively work through the challenges of moderation and community self-policing.
> - Organize the process of selecting the site's attributes (domain names, design issues, the FAQ, etc.).
> - Rally community support and drive the mission of getting publicity for the site.
>
> Essentially, **they will have the ear of the Stack Exchange team for anything we can do to help their sites succeed!**

Although the moderators pro tempore will ultimately be selected by Stack Exchange, the purpose of this post is to seek out and propose candidates:

- Each nomination should be posted as an answer and it should include (at minimum) a link to the user's main and meta profile so we can check out their activity.
- Self nominations are encouraged, step up if you feel you can help.
- If you are nominated by someone else you should edit the answer and let us know if you accept or decline (explanation optional). If a nominee declines we will not delete the answer, as to not have someone else nominate them again.
- If you are nominating someone else, please mark the post as Community Wiki before saving. Meta doesn't allow suggested edits, so your nominee may be blocked from accepting the nomination.
- The nominations are not binding to Stack Exchange or the nominees. If you are being considered by Stack Exchange, you will get an official confirmation email at one point.
- Before nominating someone or accept / decline a nomination, you should read [*A Theory of Moderation*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) thoroughly to find out what's generally expected from moderators.

If you would like to learn more about the role, please drop into [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34216/3d-printing) where you can ask about the role from other moderators (they appear with a blue name in the chat room). Another chatroom called [The Assembly](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2691/the-assembly) was created specifically for users and moderators to discuss moderation activities, moderators from all over the network are there to answer your questions.

Once again, **please don't hesitate to step up and self-nominate!**.

<sub>Thanks to [F'x](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/users/30/fx) for the original version of this post [over on chemistry](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/113/17315).</sub>

Comment: Moderatorship is not something that should be taken on on a whim - before you nominate, *think* about whether you'll have the time to commit to the site, and whether you're willing to deal with the worse side of the job  as well as the respect that comes with doing the job. If you only think you "might" like the job, wait until you've formed a more concrete opinion, or let someone else more sure do it.

Comment: Agreed @ArtOfCode, it's also important for people to understand that moderators are essentially *human exception handlers*. It can be a lot of drudge work, and it certainly ain't glamorous, but it can be satisfying knowing that you are helping a valuable resource grow and prosper.

Answer (score 15):

I would like to nominate myself, [Matt Clark](https://stackexchange.com/users/526476/matt-clark).

[image: profile for Matt Clark on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

While I might not have the wildest credentials or reputation, I have been around the StackExchange network for a while (11/2012) and generally know my way around the sites.

Mostly active on StackOverflow, I answer when I can, and try and do my part to clean up the review queue: ~5000 review tasks; I plan on giving this site as much attention as I can.

I started [this 3D Printing proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82438/3d-printing) just under a year ago on Area 51, and am either way, glad to see the day we made it to beta.

Answer (score 4):

I'll go ahead and nominate myself as well, Trais McAllister.

[image: profile for tbm0115 on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

So far, my highest reputation is held in this 3D Printing community. I've relied on the Stack Exchange network since about 2011, didn't become a member of Stack Overflow until last year. In my time on this community, I've maintained a reputation position within the top 10%, tried keeping up with the few reviews we've had thus far, and tried updating the tag definitions.

I've had my eyes in 3D printing since about 2008 when I first heard of the MakerBot Cupkake CNC and delved into the 3D printing realm in 2011 when I bought my first printer (Replicator Dual). I've learned a great deal through trial and error and am excited to help others who may be just starting in 3D printing.

As this site continues to attract more members, I've enjoyed seeing new posts and trying to help direct proper questions/answers based on the general consensus I've seen here on Meta. Although I'm not extremely involved in Meta, I do try to keep up on what's being said.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to nominate myself, [Tormod Haugene](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/users/115/tormod-haugene?tab=profile).

[profile for Tormod Haugene on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1574864.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/1574864)

I have been an active user of several Stack Exchange sites since 2012, but have finally now found a site that I really can contribute to.

As a robotics engineer by education, I early got interested in the art of 3D printing, and decided to join the community for myself in 2014 when I graduated from university. Over the past two years I have experimented with my trustworthy Kossel Mini printer to the point where I now need to set new challenges to still have something to do. Taking part in the Stack Exchange 3D Printer community has provided me further challenges and learning potential, which I truly appreciate.

I already spend a lot of time on this site, and try to help new users uphold the quality standard found on SE sites, answer questions and finish the review queues whenever possible. Overall, I am very proud of how this site has turned out so far, and would very much like to help it progress further.

To me, taking on further tasks of moderation seems like a natural step, and I hope you will allow me the opportunity to contribute as a moderator in the future.

Comment: I understand how you feel with being able to contribute! I've visited SO for about 5 years now and didn't feel capable of contributing good content until about a year and half ago.

Comment: @MarkBooth, you are right, of course. I did not at all mean a "traditional forum" in any sense; I simply didn't put any thought into that particular wording of my post. I am fully aware of the Q&A expert reference format of SE sites, which is why I use them daily, and would like to contribute to uphold the quality of their content. I will update my post accordingly!

Answer (score 2):

I would also like to nominate [Ryan Carlyle](http://stackexchange.com/users/7675951/ryan-carlyle) for moderation.

[image: profile for Ryan Carlyle on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Ryan has proven to be a valuable resource in the community by providing many well written answers and maintained a respectful record in all responses. For these reasons, I believe Ryan would be a great candidate for moderation.

Answer (score 1):

Since we still need more candidates, I would like to offer myself in a reserve position. If we don't have enough potential moderators by the time the community team need to make a decision, I would be happy to offer my time.

[profile for Mark Booth on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/18514.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/18514/mark-booth)

Although my contribution to 3d Printing so far has mostly been here on meta, I would be happy to help out as a human exception handler for our community. Plus, when I finally get around to putting my Mendel together, I'm sure I'll have a lot of questions to ask. *8')

As an active [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) over on [Robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/), I have a solid grasp of [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) and 3 years of experience, so know what the job entails. My average flag handling time over the last month has been around 12 hours, I have built up [useful](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/176/37) [tools](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to [help](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/131/37) swiftly deal with problems and I try to [involve](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1300/37) the [community](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/149/37) any [time](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/106/37) I'm not sure about how we want to [handle](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/92/37) things.

I supported the original [Personal Manufacturing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22246) site and felt passionate enough about it to create [Digital Fabrication](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41850) and take it all the way to private beta. I have also [supported](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1273/37) people asking [3d printing questions over on Robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d-printing) while getting [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82438) up and running.

Comment: I take concern with this nomination. Moderatorship needs *some* degree of activity on the main site, to demonstrate a commitment to content, and to show a level of expertise. I like that this nomination was made in good faith, but I'm not of the opinion that it should go forward, and therefore, I can't support it.

Comment: There is nothing to be concerned about @Zizouz212, I made my offer at a time when there were not enough candidates, and it is great to see more active candidates putting themselves forward and getting voted up.

Answer (score -5):

I would like to nominate myself for a moderator, I think I'd be up for the job.

http://stackexchange.com/users/6668626/chase-cromwell

I'm probably not the best candidate and I'm not super active in meta or Stack Exchange, but I'm becoming more active.